# Why css file is loading a blank page?

Tags: html, css

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content= "ie= edge">
<title>Blooger</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/style.css" />

</head>
```

I have searched a lot, checked my syntax of linking css n times and spelling of style sheet is correct, the folder I am using is correct I don't know the problem, please help.

Comment: Share folder screenshot of your HTML and CSS files

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure whether you've not added it here on SO, but your HTML file doesn't contain anything to show. (no `<body></body>` or anything within it)

As an example, you need to add

```html
<body>
<h1>My Blog</h1>
<p>welcome to my blog.</p>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check status, type and size in network tab of browser developer tool